# Automatic filter by user country ip

Tags: views

I want filter products views by user country ip. Can i use maybe rules for automatic sort, or some module? If this is not possible, as it may be possible to automatically filter on the field by the country?

Comment: Any update on the answer? is it working or not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can do this by using some of the contributed modules example is shown down 
https://www.drupal.org/node/522240

https://www.drupal.org/node/1117234

http://www.appnovation.com/blog/proximity-search-using-views-drupal

read this this will help you to find out